# Как перенести любой элемент массива по ключу выше или ниже?

Tags: php

Как перенести любой элемент массива по ключу выше или ниже?

```
$array = [
  'test' => '111',
  'test2' => '222',
  'test3' => '333',
];
```

Например `test3` сделать вторым

```
$array = [
  'test' => '111',
  'test3' => '333',
  'test2' => '222',
];
```

И так далее, вообщем поднимать или опускать по ключу

Comment: А смысл практический в этом какой?

Comment: взять массив из ключей, упорядочить как надо (найти позицию, поменять местами), пересобрать исходный вновь